# Numpy: How to add two np converted from different types?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays in different types.

```
>>> type(pred)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(label1)
<type 'tuple'>
```

converting them into np.ndarray

```
>>> nl = np.array(label1)
>>> npred = np.array(pred)
>>> type(nl)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(npred)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> nl.shape
(189,)
>>> npred.shape
(189,)
```

As you can see, the two variables `nl` and `npred` are actually of the same type and dimension.

However when I tried to subtract them, error occurs.

```
>>> nl - npred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

It's weird, isn't it?

Comment: What are `pred.shape`, `pred.dtype`, and `nl.dtype` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that although `nl` and `npred` are `numpy.ndarray` objects they can contain heterogenous data. See doc [`numpy.dtype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html):

> A numpy array is homogeneous, and contains elements described by a dtype object. A dtype object can be constructed from different combinations of fundamental numeric types.

so if `n1` is an array of strings and `npred` an array of ints you can't perform the add operation:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> b = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> type(a), type(b)
 (numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray)
>>> a + b
 unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray
```

If you want to know the content type of your arrays:

```
>>> a.dtype, b.dtype
 (dtype('S1'), dtype('int64'))
```

So, you must know which data type contain each array. It is NOT a problem of dimensions.

Comment: Exactly. It's fixed by this: `npred = np.float32(pred)`, `nl = np.float32(label1)`

Comment: Then, you are casting both arrays to the same type, so prior to that they have different dtype.

Comment: Yeah. That's the point. I thought np will do the casting between float and double. Actually `dtype(nl) = 'S5'` and `dtype(npred) = 'float64'`.

Comment: @SolessCHong - It will cast between numberic types (e.g. a float and a double, or an int and a float, etc).  A `tuple` is not a numeric type.  You're getting the same error you'd get if you just did `1 - (2, 3)` without using numpy.  The root of the problem is that `tuple`s don't have a `__sub__` method.

Comment: Not exactly. I was subtracting np.array(TUPLE) to np.array(ARRAY)